# Connected link line animation when mouse over on the node in force layout d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to make line animation like stroke-dash running when mouse over on the node. This animation should stop when mouse out.

[image]

As i searched i got a code.

```
var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();path
.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
.attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.ease("linear")
.attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

How come i make the animation till mouse over and stop when mouse out.

Comment: Make a fiddle, then we could do something on it, and get it to you...
Write on("mouseOver", function(d){ //Keep you code here }).on("mouseOut", function(d){ //Stop Animation here. });
Add this to nodes.

Comment: i have created basic layout http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/aVhd8/231/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var graph = {
    "nodes": [{
            "name": "1",
            "rating": 90,
            "id": 2951,
            "x": 90,
            "y": 50,
           "fixed": true
        }, {
            "name": "2",
            "rating": 80,
            "id": 654654,
            "x": 50,
            "y": 50,
            "fixed": true
        }, {
            "name": "3",
            "rating": 80,
            "id": 6546544,
            "x": 50,
            "y": 90,
            "fixed": true
        },

    ],
    "links": [{
            "source": 1,
            "target": 0,
            "value": 6,
            "label": "publishedOn"
        }, {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 2,
            "value": 6,
            "label": "publishedOn"
        }, {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 0,
            "value": 4,
            "label": "containsKeyword"
        },

    ]
}


var margin = {
    top: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    left: -5
};
var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-200)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom]);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
     .scaleExtent([.1, 1])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
 
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);


var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")").call(zoom);

var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

var container = svg.append("g");

//d3.json('http://blt909.free.fr/wd/map2.json', function(error, graph) {



force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

var movement = 200;

var link = container.append("g")
   // .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    })
    //.attr("transform", function(d) {
    //    return "translate(" + movement + "," + 0 + ")";
    //})
.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
; 


var node = container
    .selectAll(".node").append("g")
    
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")

    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .call(drag)
;

node.append("circle")

    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.weight * 2 + 12;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(1 / d.rating);
    })
    //.attr("transform", function(d) {
    //    return "translate(" + movement + "," + 0 + ")";
    //})
//.call(drag)
; //Here you move the nodes

force.on("tick", tick);

function tick(){
//force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        //Here i create a node radius so it doesnt go offscreen
        var nodeRadius = d.weight * 2 + 12
        
        //here I do checks to see if it goes offscreen
        if(d.x<= nodeRadius){
           d.x = nodeRadius;
           }
        if(d.y<= nodeRadius){
           d.y = nodeRadius;
           }7
        if(d.x>width - nodeRadius){
           d.x = width - nodeRadius;
           }
        if(d.y>height - nodeRadius){
           d.y = height - nodeRadius;
           }
        
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        
    });
}

var linkedByIndex = {};
graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
}

node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    link.attr("stroke-dasharray", 10 + " " + 10)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 500)
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
    
    
    node.classed("node-active", function(o) {
        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
        return thisOpacity;
    });

    link.classed("link-active", function(o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
    });

    d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", (d.weight * 2 + 12) * 1.5);
})

.on("mouseout", function(d) {

  link.attr("stroke-dasharray", 0).attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
    node.classed("node-active", false);
    link.classed("link-active", false);

    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", d.weight * 2 + 12);
});


function dottype(d) {
    d.x = +d.x;
    d.y = +d.y;
    return d;
}

function zoomed() {
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
    force.start();
}

function dragged(d) {
    force.stop();
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
    
     
    tick(); 

}

function dragended(d) {
    d.fixed = true;

    //d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
    tick();
}
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node-active{
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-opacity: .3;
}

.link-active {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#map{
    border: 2px #555 dashed;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Hope you are looking for this,

**Description for the code**
In mouse over function I've added below lines of code

```
link.attr("stroke-dasharray", 10 + " " + 10)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 500)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

above I'm setting stroke-dasharray attribute with "10 10" this will make line to be displayed in dashed style like - - - -, next 
setting stroke-dashoffset with 500 this value makes the dashes to move faster means value changes 0 to 500 in the time span of 2000 milliseconds which is mentioned in duration(2000) of transition above you can see that.
After completion of transition I'm changing stroke-dashoffset to 0 to make it as line,

And also in mouseout function I've added below line

```
link.attr("stroke-dasharray", 0).attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

This will make the lines again from dashed to single line.

And For more observation
Once you mouseover to any circle the animation will started and it'll continued for 2seconds, but within 2seconds if you mouseover to the circle you can see the animation which is activated previously and still running. So that is left for your choice whether to play the animation for 2seconds or not, hope you understood where to change the value for this,
And one more thing is when you want to make it as a single line, 
immediately when the mouseout is fired or after the animation is completed.
These two things need to be observed.

Hope you understood every thing, If not ask me.
Okay.I might have done this yesterday, due to time and system availability.

Comment: Thank you Saikiran. :) I think this will be a good start for me.But Animation should be infinity  till mouse over. Any how i got it..

Comment: function animate(){ link.attr("stroke-dasharray", 10 + " " + 10)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 500)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0).each("end", animate);}

Comment: Oh...What a goodness. You got it..it's animating infinity. Whoa!